# Alamofire does not want to accept my parameters in the query - it says extra argument in the call

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I wrote a function in `swift` for fetching data based on different parameters. The very beginning of the function is:

```
func makePostQuery(_ parameters: [String:AnyObject], url: String)
{

    Alamofire.request(url, parameters: (parameters), method: .post)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
```

but the problem is that `(parameters)` is highlighted and raises error:

```
Extra argument `parameters` in call
```

The parameters for example are constructed like this:

```
var params = [
        "long": lon as AnyObject,
        "lat": lat as AnyObject,
        "startDate": DateCalc.convertValueToDate(defaults.float(forKey: "startDate")) as AnyObject
        ] as [String: AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong order of parameters. Try this instead:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Alamofire 4.0 , use

```
request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
```

and you don't need cast all parameters . Just write it like this:

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["bar" : foo ,"baz" : 1]
```